# Acumatica: Web Service Endpoint Migration

Tags: web-services, acumatica

How do I migrate a web service endpoint to new system without having to recreate it from scratch on the new system? Basically move it from dev to production.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a customization package where you can added your web service endpoints and publish it in production.